# WPF ListView ContextMenu

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding, contextmenu

[Gitea Repo](https://gitea.kaaaxcreators.de/kaaax0815/hexo-gui)
I have a WPF C# Application with a `ListView` and there inside is a `GridView`.

```xml
<ListView Name="Entries">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
            <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
                </Style>
            </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Type" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Type}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Title" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Title}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Date" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Date}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Tags" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Tags}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Categories" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Categories}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

When I right click on of the `ListViewItem`s, a `ContextMenu` should come up and when I click on it, it should execute a function.
Something like this:

```cs
private void EntryClick(<identifier of click>) {
    MessageBox.Show("Clicked " + <maybe title to identify what i clicked>);
}
```

Everywhere I found this, but I don't know what to do with it:

```
<MenuItem ... CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,ListBox,1}} />
```

Then I found this: [WPF Get name of ListView item when ContextMenu clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59296606/wpf-get-name-of-listview-item-when-contextmenu-clicked) But I don't anything for `item.Name`

Edit: 
I added

```xml
<ListView.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Header="Remove"
            Command="{Binding RemoveItem}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItem}" />
    </ContextMenu>
</ListView.ContextMenu>
```

and

```cs
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;

private ICommand _removeItem;

public ICommand RemoveItem
{
    get { return _removeItem ?? (_removeItem = new RelayCommand(p => RemoveItemCommand((string)p))); }
}

private void RemoveItemCommand(string item)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item))
        MessageBox.Show(item);

}
```

But now I get this error:

> Delegate System.Action does not take 1 arguments

I installed the NuGet package `GalaSoft.MvvmLight` because I didn't have `RelayCommand`. Was this right or do I have to create a class?

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11082573/1997232).

Comment: @Sinatr check my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original `CommandParameter` binding does not work because a `ContextMenu` is not part of the same visual tree as the control it is associated with and the ancestor type is wrong (`ListBox` instead of `ListView`). The original binding below translates to *find the first parent of type `ListBox`, get its `SelectedItem`* and assign it as `CommandParameter`.

```
<MenuItem CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, ListBox, 1}} />
```

What you can do instead is leverage the fact that the `PlacementTarget` property of the `ContextMenu` contains a reference to the associated control (here `ListView`). So the following binding translates to *find the parent `ContextMenu`, get the `SelectedItem` of its associated control* and assign it as `CommandParameter`.

```
<MenuItem Header="Remove"
          Command="{Binding RemoveItem}"
          CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItem}" />
```

> Delegate System.Action does not take 1 arguments

You get this error because you use the wrong command type. A [`RelayCommand`](https://github.com/lbugnion/mvvmlight/blob/master/GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight%20(PCL)/Command/RelayCommand.cs) constructor takes an execute delegate of type [`Action`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action?view=net-5.0). This delelgate does not take any parameters.

```
public RelayCommand(Action execute, bool keepTargetAlive = false)
```

What you were looking for is the generic [`RelayCommand<T>`](https://github.com/lbugnion/mvvmlight/blob/master/GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight%20(PCL)/Command/RelayCommandGeneric.cs) that takes an [`Action<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=net-5.0).

```
public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute, bool keepTargetAlive = false)
```

Adapt your property to use a `RelayCommand<string>`, no need for casting to `string` here.

```
public ICommand RemoveItem
{
    get { return _removeItem ?? (_removeItem = new RelayCommand<string>(RemoveItemCommand)); }
}
```

---

Update for your comment. Your `RemoveItem` command is defined in the code-behind of your window. Since you are doing code-behind anyway and access your controls directly to set `ItemsSource` and so on you could set the `DataContext` of the window to itsself in the constructor.

```
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   
   // ...your other code.

   DataContext = this;
}
```

The data context is inherited in controls, so to acces the `RemoveItem` command on the data context, you can use the same approach as above with the `PlacementTarget`.

```
<MenuItem Header="Remove"
          Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext.RemoveItem}" 
          CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItem}" />
```

Please note that there are countless ways to fix this issue, using the `DataContext` is only one, but since it is unclear which design approach you are following, it is hard to give a definitive answer. Consider looking into the MVVM pattern, which will make these kinds of issues much easier.

---

Update to your comment that you get an `InvalidCastException`.

> hexo_gui.Entries" cant be converted to "System.String".

That is because the items collection holds items of type `Entries`, **not** `string`, but in your command you expect a `string`, hence the exception. Adapt your command to expect an `Entries` instance.

```
public ICommand RemoveItem => _removeItem ?? (_removeItem = new RelayCommand<Entries>(RemoveItemCommand));
private void RemoveItemCommand(Entries item)
{
   // No item was selected.
   if (item == null)
      return;

   // Do something with the item.
}
```

Comment: I did what you saided, but it does nothing.could you look in my [repo](https://gitea.kaaaxcreators.de/kaaax0815/hexo-gui)?

Comment: @kaaaxcreators I looked into it, see my update.

Comment: Error `System.InvalidCastException` "hexo_gui.Entries" cant be converted to "System.String". Also updates repo maybe i did something wrong

Comment: @kaaaxcreators See my update, you expect the wrong type in your command.